# Dealing with jsonfield migration dependency Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, upgrade

I am busy preparing a Django 1.9 project for an upgrade. I had 1 model that was using a jsonfield (which is no longer supported), thankfully it was a model that was no longer in use, so I just got rid of it.

I have now uninstalled the jsonfield package, and now I am running into a ModuleNot Found Error, because of the existence of the jsonField in my migration files.

What would be the best way to deal with this?

Comment: I'd probably edit the migration files. If you want to keep a JSONField around, django introduced its own in 1.9 so you could change the imports to use that.

Comment: Thanks @markwalker So essentially if I change the import to use the django JSONField, it should work?

What would I need to import? Currently what I have in my migrations is
import jsonfield.fields

Comment: `from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField`

Comment: If you're not using postgres, then django-extensions has a version; https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/db/fields/json.py

Comment: I am using Postgres. Thanks very much, this seems to have solved my problem.